# Anaconda distribution of json package acting differently than standard distribution?

Tags: json, python-3.x, flask, anaconda, miniconda

I use the Miniconda distribution of Python. When trying to run a flask web app, the code crashes on a call to `json.dumps(aDict)`, saying `TypeError: keys must be a string`. Switching to a distribution of Python installed via homebrew, the error disappears-- integer keys are simply cast into strings.

Is it really possible that the Anaconda version of the `json` module has different behavior than other distributions? Or could something else be going on?

Comment: Can you share what the `aDict` is in this case?

Comment: Also can you share which versions of Python3 you are using in miniconda and with brew? Can you also try to create a conda environment with the same version of Python from Homebrew to see if the error still works? My initial guess is that this is because of the specific version of Python that you are using. If you can post a MWE that would be great.